# Global variable not working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

below is my code

`glb.h`:

```
extern int var;
```

`glb.cpp`:

```
int var =0;
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <glb.h>

int var1 = 100;
var = var1;
```

i need to use globals but when i cross compile on raspberry pi the global variable (var)is not showing any value. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not really pi specific, you should tag it C++ instead. What does "not showing" mean in your case? Does the value not change? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: The value is o but it should change to 100. There's no compiler error

Comment: Maybe not `"int var 1"` but `"int var1"`?

Comment: i tried both, result is still 0.

Comment: What fix your tipo plz... and you can't define a global twice provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't reproduce == no answer.

Comment: come on, it was a typo error, when i tried to type it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `main.cpp` file which has statements outside of any function. Something like this:

```
var = var1;
```

must be in a function. The only thing that can be in the global scope is declarations, and initial assignments. Put it inside a main function and it works.

As an aside, your usage of `#include <>` is non-standard. Usually double quotes (`"`) are used for your own headers in the same directory, and the angle brackets are used to include standard system headers.